# The same distance covered on a flat and an undulating terrain; Is this the same?

Tags: calculus

I am working on a problem related to measuring distances. Seems to be somewhat philosophical, which is no good to this forum, but I thought it was worth throwing out there.

The distance is two miles. Over two separate terrains, one absolutely flat and the other has sharp undulations.

Assuming a runner is running over both, are these distances the same? More to the point, is one 'tougher' than the other and, if so, how best to quantify that?

I have taken a snapshot from Google Earth that captures the terrain of a distance of 2 miles. I am wondering if there was a way to deduce what the 'actual' distance is. By 'actual' I mean, what it feels like.

[Terrain Snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDVbB.png)

Comment: So let's say that we have two points connected by a straight line and a curve that's not the same as the straight line. Of course the straight line is shorter than the curve length. I don't think that needs any proof. But how to quantify the "toughness", is another question ...

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has tried it knows running over undulating terrain is harder than running over flat terrain.  The challenge is to make a model that reflects the reality.  There is an analogy to swimming up and down a river, where the model to add the river speed to your swimming speed is simple and we can prove it takes longer in a current than in still water.

It is hard to say how to model the effort or speed change caused by running on a hill.  If running uphill is slower by the same amount as running downhill is faster the same proof as the river applies.  It is because you spend more time going uphill than downhill.

If you measure distance along the ground you can make a hilly course that is easier and faster.  Make a flat spot at points that perfectly match the runner's stride and lots of short wiggles in between.  The wiggles will mean that the horizontal distance to travel two miles is shorter than two miles, but the flat spots mean the running is just as easy.

Comment: In fact you don't even have to bother with the flat spots.  Just have the "hills" on a scale of a millimetre or so.  The runner will only notice improved traction.  Of course, nobody would really measure the distance along millimetre-size wiggles.

Comment: Exactly right. However, with the aid of Google Earth, I can get an accurate snapshot of the elevations, etc. I am hoping to show that a 2mile run on a flat surface compared to that of terrain with multiple elevations/troughs is apples to oranges. 

Where I am coming unstuck is how to capture these differences in a quantifiable manner.

I have the time taken and terrain characteristics (see link in OP). I am just thinking of the best way to show that one runner was "better" than the other.